# Import 2000 posts from one website to another

Tags: plugins, post-thumbnails, migration

I need to import 2000 posts from one website to another. Posts doesn't have any custom fields. We need to import title, content, featured image, slug and language. For language I am using Polylang plugin.

Using WordPress import and export I can import all the posts. In this way language with category is selected but featured images keeps showing loading gif and I cannot see any image there. I need to move also these images in Media folder on a new site

I have triad also WP All Import plugin, content category and featured imag works in a perfect way but in this case language is not selected.

Can you suggest me on how to import 2000 posts using Polylang language ?

Comment: try with this plugin UpdraftPlus

Comment: Can you import posts only with updraftplus ? Is it a WordPress Restore plugin or not ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, use this plugin, [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-featured-images/) will help you in exporting all featured images either it's of any post type. Follow these steps:

1. Export all images from the existing website and import it in the new one.
2. After the images have been imported successfully, now continue with the importing of posts/post types.

Importing Images first will get all the images of that post type, and when you will import posts these images will be assigned to respective posts.

Comment: thnx for your reply, I will try it now :)